# In HTML5 canvas shape change on button click?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas, css-animations

I just want to know that is there any website that give brief information about canvas.
I am working on my project. in which one canvas and 4 buttons.
These are four buttons:CIRCLE, RECTANGLE, SQUARE and ANIMATED RAINBOW.

When I click on circle button in canvas animated circle are shown when I click on rectangle button that time circle are changes into rectangle in ease in/out style in animation. Shapes changes into another shapes but in animated style on canvas.

I read lots of article watch many videos but I cannot find a solution.
Below I show an image.

[image: Layout what I need]

If any one tell me and give me some suggestion where I go for study.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make 4 different functions in JavaScript circle, rectangle, square, rainbow.
And make 4 different classes in case like that.
Then set the value of convas class according to shape in JavaScript functions.
Like if you click on circle button.
First set HTML code.

```
<button id = "circle" onclick ="circle"></button>
```

When user click on this button it will call circle function write code like that in circle function in JavaScript.

```
function circle(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.class = "circle";
    //This is class name which you have to make in case
}
```